# dpkg can't install pgAdmin4-web on my debian

Tags: pgadmin-4

I tried installing `pgadmin4` on `debian10` and it reported:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/pgadmin4-web_4.24_all.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/etc/apache2/conf-available/pgadmin4.conf', which is also in package pgadmin4-apache2 4.23-1.pgdg100+1
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

Try `force-overwriting` :

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/pgadmin4-web_4.24_all.deb

sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 4):

I just want to extend the answer of **Thirumal**. Just
try to get into

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

You will find the exact version of your pgadmin4-web there.The version at the time of writing this answer is

> pgadmin4-web_4.28_all.deb

After you locate your own version then apply the following two commands

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/pgadmin4-web_YOUR VERSION_all.deb

sudo apt-get -f install
```